# I just want UTF-8, period. Not with or without BOM

Tags: encoding, utf-8

Using all those techniques like:

```
{ 
   "Default_encoding": "UTF-8",
    "font_size": 9,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

and even when I save with UTF-8 encoding, always remains `UTF-8` without `BOM` (Notepad ++ check).

No! I just want UTF-8, period. Not with or without BOM.

What do I do?

Comment: Your original message title gives the impression that you have a question about Sublime Text 2. But in reality, you seem to have a bone to pick with Notepad++ developers, because instead of "UTF-8" only, they've written "UTF-8 without BOM". Your questions is analogous to "I don't want 'Mr. Smith without wife'. I want 'Mr. Smith', period!"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shows a complete lack of understanding of English to the point of absurdity, and is useless to anybody other than the questioner

Comment: Your question is like saying You don't want a car with a radio and you don't want a car without a radio, you just want a car.

If a program describes something as UTF-8, then it's not telling you whether it has a BOM or doesn't have it. But it's going to be one or the other.

Notepad++ is simply telling you the truth. All UTF-8 files will always be either with the BOM or without the BOM.

Answer (score 1):

Standard UTF-8 encoding **is** UTF-8 without a BOM (Byte-Order Mark). Please read [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for more details. Either the BOM is there, or it is not. Your encoding is fine.